# Rendering to the screen in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I'm creating my own 2D engine.  I planned on just using the .net drawing functions.  However, this is extremely slow and the screen flashes a lot.  I have to draw it to a window, however...

What is the best way to do this?  How would I add buffers to the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using GDI, the "screen" flashing problem is due to writing directly over the primary surface. You can avoid this by creating a "Bitmap" buffer, by doing something like this:

```
Bitmap buffer = New Bitmap(Me.ClientSize.Width, Me.ClientSize.Height)
```

Then creating a managed "Graphics" object from that buffer,

```
Using gfx As Graphics = New Graphics.FromImage( buffer )

// draw with gfx object

End Using
```

To display the updated back buffer on the primary surface, something like:

PrimaryGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(buffer, 0, 0) or you can P/Invoke "[BitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt)", which I believe is a bit faster.

If you were using C# I would suggest using "unsafe" code blocks to manipulate the buffer directly via pointers, which can speed things up quite a bit. However, I don't believe VB.net supports them.

Edit:

GDI+ is not really going to be "blazing" fast no matter what due to the way it's implemented using standard system CPU / Memory resources.

You could look into using [SlimDX](https://github.com/mrvux/SlimDX), which has a managed wrapper around Direct2D, a hardware accelerated 2D API. There are some [tutorials](http://slimdx.org/tutorials/basicwindow.php) available for getting started.

Edit 2:

If you stick with GDI, you can use "LockBits" on your back buffer to do some "optimized" memory operations, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx) is a great article on the subject.

Comment: There’s one `New` too many in your code. Furthermore, manipulating blocked pixel arrays is possible in VB as well as C#, unsafe code isn’t necessary here (though it may be slightly faster because it might omit index out of bounds checks).

Comment: @Konrad I realized you can use the bmp.LockBits() with the "Marshal" object and copy pixel arrays back and forth, however there is a quite a bit of overhead in doing that versus "( ptr * ) bmp.Scan0 + ( offset ) = val". :)

Comment: True. I don’t think there’s a way in VB of eliding this unnecessary copy. But even so `LockBits` is faster than manipulating pixels via `SetPixel`.

Comment: @Konrad I definitely agree, but we should probably let OP get a handle on a flip chain before we throw him to the wolves, ha. I'll update post with some additional info. Good points.